# Cant find “Manage In-App purchases” under itunes connect

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I know i am going to ask something that might sound bit odd, but still asking

I am developing an application that has In App Purchase functionality, i have integrated the code but for testing i need to make a test account under iTunes connect. During R&D i came to know that i have to go through following way to make test account for in app purchase:

iTunes Connect-> “Manage In-App purchases”

My problem is that i am not able to see the option “Manage In-App purchases” under iTunes connect. Any kind of input to this question would be great help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 14):

Have you signed the "Paid Applications"-contract? You need to sign it in order to manage in app purchases or set up test users. You find it in iTunes Connect under "Contracts, Tax & Banking Information".

Comment: I don't see any sort of link for the Paid Applications contract under Contracts, Tax, & Banking Information.  Do I need to upload a binary before this appears?

Comment: This is not obvious at all.... :-( Leave the button and when someone click in the button a dialog message says: "Please sign the contract first!". It is not rocket science...

Comment: You saved my day. There are two Apples: one, the master of design and simplicity is the one who designs devices and software for the consumer, the other one is controlled by Darth Vader, hates developers, write crappy vague documentation and designs iTunesConnect, application loader, Xcode and other crappy stuff. I hope the good one destroys the death star of the second one, one day.

Comment: @RubberDuck : Apple is like a benevolent dictator. He knows what you should do and how you should do it, and if you just submit and accept his wisdom without question you can live happily in Appleland. If you want to do things differently, he will punish you so that you can see the true light of his wisdom. You can of course leave Appleland... but you must leave all that you hold dear, and rebuild your future from scratch in a foreign land.

Comment: can we have the other good apple controlling Appleland? This darth vader one stinks.

Answer (score 5):

From iTunes connect Developer guide 6.3

> If you do not see the Manage In App
>   Purchases module on your iTunes
>   Connect Home page, it could be one of
>   these reasons:
>
> - You are not an Admin or Technical    user for your iTunes Connect account.
> - You do not have the latest Paid    Applications contract in effect.
> - Your Team Agent has not clicked    through the latest iOS Developer
>     Program License Agreement.
>
> If you have fulfilled all of these
>   requirements yet still do not see the
>   module, you can contact iTunes Connect
>   Support for more details by using the
>   Contact Us module on the Home page.

Answer (score 3):

This has changed.  Updated details as per iTunes Connect support pages.

> **Frequently Asked Questions:**
>   *Why do I not see the Manage Your In-App Purchases module?*
>
> The tools in the Manage Your In-App Purchases module have been moved
>   to the Manage Your Applications module. You can now manage your In-App
>   Purchases from the app summary page for a specific app in the Manage
>   Your Applications module.
>
> To be able to create and edit In-App Purchases, you must be an Admin
>   or Technical user for your iTunes Connect account. You must also have
>   the latest version of the Paid Applications contract in effect and
>   must have at least one paid app in iTunes Connect under Manage Your
>   Applications.
>
> If you think that the in app purchase module should be on for your
>   account and is currently disabled, please contact us.

Answer (score 1):

It's under "Manage Users":

```
Manage Users
Create and manage both iTunes Connect and In App Purchase Test User accounts.
```

After you click "Manage Users", it's the option on the right ("In App Purchase Test User").

Comment: Still cant find the option all i can see is "add new user" and previous user names and edit options

Comment: Still cant find the option all i can see is "add new user" and previous user names and edit options

Answer (score 1):

Now it stays on the details of the app. Access iTunesConnect and select a app. The 'Manage In App Purchase' will be in the right-top menu.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this apple help tutorial.

Its perfect :-

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1329/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

iTunes Connect -> My Apps -> Select your app -> select 'Features' tab

[image]